# Using url parameter in a class based view to set form field

Tags: python, django, forms

I am creating a form in my django app. My app has a user, a user can have many transactions and a transaction can have many sales. I'm trying to create a form to add sales to the DB. I'm trying to pass a parameter in the URL (transaction_id) and use it in the Django class-based view CreateView to set the corresponding (foreign key) field in the form. Is it possible to do this and if so how could I apply it.

Class based create view below

```
class SaleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Sale
    fields = ['amount_sold', 'total_price_sold', 'note']

    def form_valid(self, form):
```

URL below

```
path('sale/new/<int:pk>', SaleCreateView.as_view(), name='sale-create'),
```

Link below

```
{% url 'sale-create' transaction.id %}
```

Sale form below

```
<div>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class ="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Enter Sale</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class ="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Enter</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You will need to use a `ModelForm` with `CreateView`. Your `SaleCreateView` with `SaleCreateForm` classes should look like this:

```
class SaleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Transaction
    fields = ['amount_sold', 'total_price_sold', 'note']
    form_class = SaleCreateForm

    def get_initial(self, *args, **kwargs):
            initial = super(SaleCreateView, self).get_initial(**kwargs)
            return initial

class SaleCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        exclude = ('transaction',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.transaction = kwargs.pop('transaction')
        super(SaleCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is a [step by step tutorial](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/01/django-createview/).